# How to resize LVM disk in Debian 8.6 without losing data

Tags: debian, fdisk, resize2fs

I need to resize my first disk (/dev/xvda) from 40 GB to 80 GB. I'm using XEN virtualization, and the disk is resized in XenCenter, but I need to resize its partitions without losing any data. The virtual machine is running Debian 8.6.

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 80 GiB, 85 899 345 920 bajtů, 167 772 160 sektorů
Jednotky: sektorů po 1 * 512 = 512 bajtech
Velikost sektoru (logického/fyzického): 512 bajtů / 512 bajtů
Velikost I/O (minimální/optimální): 512 bajtů / 512 bajtů
Typ popisu disku: dos
Identifikátor disku: 0x5a0b8583

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1        2048   499711   497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/xvda2      501758 83884031 83382274 39,8G  5 Extended
/dev/xvda5      501760 83884031 83382272 39,8G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/xvdb: 64 GiB, 68 719 476 736 bajtů, 134 217 728 sektorů
Jednotky: sektorů po 1 * 512 = 512 bajtech
Velikost sektoru (logického/fyzického): 512 bajtů / 512 bajtů
Velikost I/O (minimální/optimální): 512 bajtů / 512 bajtů
Typ popisu disku: gpt
Identifikátor disku: 0596FDE3-F7B7-46C6-8CE1-03C0B0ADD20A

Device     Start       End   Sectors Size Type
/dev/xvdb1  2048 134217694 134215647  64G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/mapper/xenhosting--vg-root: 38,1 GiB, 40 907 046 912 bajtů, 79 896 576 sektorů
Jednotky: sektorů po 1 * 512 = 512 bajtech
Velikost sektoru (logického/fyzického): 512 bajtů / 512 bajtů
Velikost I/O (minimální/optimální): 512 bajtů / 512 bajtů
Disk /dev/mapper/xenhosting--vg-swap_1: 1,7 GiB, 1 782 579 200 bajtů, 3 481 600 sektorů
Jednotky: sektorů po 1 * 512 = 512 bajtech
Velikost sektoru (logického/fyzického): 512 bajtů / 512 bajtů
Velikost I/O (minimální/optimální): 512 bajtů / 512 bajtů
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be relatively easy, since you're using LVM:

1. First, as always, take a backup.
2. Resize the disk in Xen (you've already done this; despite this, please re-read step 1).
3. Use parted to resize the extended partition (`xvda2`); run `parted /dev/xvda`, then at the parted prompt `resizepart 2 -1s` to resize it to end at the end of the disk (BTW: `quit` will get out of parted).
4. **Either** (a) create another logical partition (`xvda6`) with the free space, then:

   1. reboot to pick up the partition table changes
   2. `pvcreate /dev/xvda6`
   3. `vgextend xenhosting-vg /dev/xvda6`

   **or** (b)

   1. extend xvda5 using `resizepart 5 -1s`
   2. reboot to pick up the partition table changes
   3. `pvresize /dev/xvda5`
5. Finally, if you want to add that to your root filesystem, `lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/xenhosting-vg/root`. The `-r` option to `lvextend` tells it to call `resize2fs` itself.

Another option you didn't consider:

Add another virtual disk. If you can do this in Xen w/o rebooting the guest, then you can do this entirely online (without any reboots). Partition the new disk `xvdc` (this will not requite a reboot, since its not in use), then proceed with `pvcreate` & `vgextend` using `/dev/xvdc1`.

Comment: @OldřichŠvéda that's a command inside `parted` ... you'd run `parted /dev/xda` first, then execute that. I'll clarify

Comment: Are the reboots really necessary to pick up the partition table changes? AFAIK `partprobe` is enough. And for step 4b, my man for `resizepart` says it takes 3 args and that it "doesn't manipulate partitions on hard drive". So, that seems redundant with next step (reboot) and apparently, a step is missing to actually resize the partition on disk.

Comment: @xhienne `partprobe` won't work on disks that are in use. Unfortunately. You must have a different version of parted; that's not what's in Debian 8.6, though (or stretch, for that matter). See, e.g., https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/resizepart.html#resizepart

Comment: Ooops, I missed the fact that `resizepart` was a `parted` subcommand (not mentioned in my parted man, good to know) and I was referring to the resizepart shell command. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running Devuan Jessie 1.0 (Stable) in a VM on ProxMox. The partition I needed to extend was `/var/lib` mounted on `/dev/sda5` for elasticsearch.  Since this wasn't OS critical, I could do it with the VM up. I just ensured that there was nothing using the partition with `lsof`.   To accomplish this, I did the following:

1. Check the partition to make sure it's not busy:

   ```
   lsof /dev/sda5
   ```

   - If you get any output from this command, you must determine what is using the partition in question and terminate the process. Here is a reference. [LSOF Comand Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples)
2. Unmount the partition:

   ```
   umount /dev/sda5
   ```
3. Run parted

   ```
   parted
   ```
4. Inside parted:

   ```
   resizepart 5 -1s
   ```
5. Quit parted:

   ```
   quit
   ```
6. Check the disk:

   ```
   e2fsck -f /dev/sda5
   ```
7. Extend the disk so the OS sees it:

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/sda5
   ```
8. Remount:

   ```
   mount -a.
   ```
9. Check to make sure the OS sees the newly extended drive:

   ```
   df -h /dev/sda5
   ```

Now everything should be good to go. On a side note, `lvextend` threw an error, so for me, the `resize2fs` route was the simplest way to go. HTH.

Comment: The `lsof` might be redundant, since the `umount` will fail if anything is using the filesystem  — but better safe than sorry.

Comment: I'm a Marine, so when I write a walk-through, I assume the reader has no prior knowledge. For a reader with no prior knowledge, an error when unmounting could throw them off track and would be very frustrating. I'm just trying to enable the masses.

Comment: Well, I said “might”. My point is you could just leave out the `lsof` and add a note to the `umount` that, if it fails, the user should look at the error message and check whether the filesystem is in use. For that matter, you say “I assume the reader has no prior knowledge.”, but you don’t explain what to do with the `lsof` results. I had a customer once who damaged a database by doing Step A and then Step B without realizing that he had to inspect the output of Step A to verify that it was safe to proceed with Step B. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. Thank you for your service.

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, you make a good point.